# How do I write NOT Operation for the Risc-V (Assembly Language)?

Tags: assembly, bitwise-operators, riscv, bitwise-not

How do I write NOT Operation for the Risc-V (Assembly Language)? If there's no NOT instruction, how do you achieve the same thing?

Comment: If you mean a bitwise not, you can `XOR` with -1.

Comment: In general, ask a C compiler to compile with optimization enabled (in this case  `return ~x;`).  https://godbolt.org/ has RISC-V compilers.  (It may use a `not` pseudo-instruction, though, so you'd need to look at machine code to find the real machine instruction.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like MIPS and some other architectures, RISC V does not provide dedicated instructions for many things, including two-operand unary operations, as these operations can be had using their three-operand format, usually with `x0` as the third operand, but sometimes constant `1` or `-1` as the third operand.

For convenience, the assembler will accept what are called ***Pseudo Instructions*** for these unary operations (and others).  Here's a list of the common RISC V pseudo instructions and their replacements.

To do more complex or unlisted things, use math & logic, and as many instructions as needed.

```
Pseudo Instruction   | Expansion                      | Function
---------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------
nop                  | addi x0, x0, 0                 | No operation
li rd, immediate     | Myriad sequences               | Load immediate
mv rd, rs            | addi rd, rs, 0                 | Copy register
not rd, rs           | xori rd, rs, -1                | One’s complement
neg rd, rs           | sub rd, x0, rs                 | Two’s complement
negw rd, rs          | subw rd, x0, rs                | Two’s complement word
sext.w rd, rs        | addiw rd, rs, 0                | Sign extend word
seqz rd, rs          | sltiu rd, rs, 1                | Set if = zero
snez rd, rs          | sltu rd, x0, rs                | Set if ̸= zero
sltz rd, rs          | slt rd, rs, x0                 | Set if < zero
sgtz rd, rs          | slt rd, x0, rs                 | Set if > zero
beqz rs, offset      | beq rs, x0, offset             | Branch if = zero
bnez rs, offset      | bne rs, x0, offset             | Branch if ̸= zero
blez rs, offset      | bge x0, rs, offset             | Branch if ≤ zero
bgez rs, offset      | bge rs, x0, offset             | Branch if ≥ zero
bltz rs, offset      | blt rs, x0, offset             | Branch if < zero
bgtz rs, offset      | blt x0, rs, offset             | Branch if > zero
bgt rs, rt, offset   | blt rt, rs, offset             | Branch if >
ble rs, rt, offset   | bge rt, rs, offset             | Branch if ≤
bgtu rs, rt, offset  | bltu rt, rs, offset            | Branch if >, unsigned
bleu rs, rt, offset  | bgeu rt, rs, offset            | Branch if ≤, unsigned
j offset             | jal x0, offset                 | Jump
jal offset           | jal x1, offset                 | Jump and link
jr rs                | jalr x0, 0(rs)                 | Jump register
jalr rs              | jalr x1, 0(rs)                 | Jump and link register
ret                  | jalr x0, 0(x1)                 | Return from subroutine
call aa              | auipc x1, aa[31 : 12] + aa[11] | Call far-away subroutine
                     | jalr x1, aa[11:0](x1)          | (two instructions)
tail aa              | auipc x6, aa[31 : 12] + aa[11] | Tail call far-away subroutine
                     | jalr x0, aa[11:0](x6)          | (also two instructions)
```

---

As an aside, there's an educational processor called the LC-3.  It has only three arithmetic/logical operations: `ADD`, `AND`, `NOT`.  Yet students are expected to write code that does multiplication, division, modulus, `XOR`, `OR`, etc..!!  Multiplication & division/modulus are done with a loop; `XOR` and `OR` are done using logic sequences — we know all the boolean operation can be had using only NAND gates, so having (only) `AND` & `NOT` is primitive but sufficient.

My favorite sequence for `XOR` on that processor comes from this formula:

```
(A AND NOT B) + (NOT A AND B)
```

Where here the `+` is literally `ADD`, which works as a substitute for `OR` because the two operands will never both be 1 at the same time, so carry from one bit position to another will not occur, and under those circumstances, `ADD` and `OR` are equivalent.