# Assembly what is ret?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am new to assembly and I saw the following line of code

```
ret
```

What does it do? I looked in my RiscV Green Card but didn't find it. Is it like `j`, does it store or load any data?

Comment: Well its a jump. It is a pseudo instruction. Its effectively a `jalr x0, x1, 0 `. `x1` hold the return address.

Comment: @Eraklon to make things clear it just jumps to the value stored in x1(ra)?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: would you like to post it as answer?

Comment: [RISC V Pseudo instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65008687/471129)

Comment: what part of the documentation is not clear?

Answer (score 8):

It is a pseudo instruction. It is eqvivalent to `jalr x0, x1, 0`. `x1` holds the return address. Effectively jumping to the return address.

For more info on JALR see page 16 [here](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf).