# how to use comparison operators is riscv(<=, >=)

Tags: assembly, riscv

im having trouble understanding how to do the rs1 **>=** rs2 and rs1 **<=** rs2 by using only **slt**, **slti** and **xori**.I know how to do rs1 **<** rs2 but i cant really find a way to do the <= without using **bne**, anyone has an idea?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to do less than or equal in Assembly Language(MIPS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22736836) - my answer there even mentions that RISC-V does it the same way as MIPS, and shows compiler output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you looking for as an answer?  Trying to get a boolean value into a register, or to branch to target -- those would have different answers.

Since the limitations include `xori`, we'll assume the former.  The `xori` instruction can be used to negate a boolean value.  If you don't understand how that might be done, look up negate aka NOT on MIPS or RISC V, e.g. [How do I write NOT Operation for the Risc-V (Assembly Language)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006052/how-do-i-write-not-operation-for-the-risc-v-assembly-language/65008687#65008687)

So, to do `rs1 <= rs2`, we would do `! (rs2 < rs1)` which is logically the same as `rs2 >= rs1` which is logically the same as `rs1 <= rs2`.

The difference is that `! (rs2 < rs1)` is directly implementable given the MIPS instruction set and your limitations.

---

Were you looking to branch on `<=` instead of generating a boolean value, we would compute `rs2 < rs1` and then branch on false (using `beq .. $0`) instead of branch on true using (`bne .. $0`).

---

All 6 relational operations can be had this way.  The tools in your tool kit are: swap operand sides, negate the boolean, and/or branch on false vs. branch on true.

Comment: Was trying to get a boolean into a register, Thank you, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

ask the compiler.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int ret;
    
    ret=0;
    if(a<b) ret=1;
    return(ret);
}
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   00b53533            sltu    x10,x10,x11
   4:   8082                    c.jr    x1
```

Comment: Why over-complicate that C source like that, vs. `return (a<b);`?

Comment: I was doing other things with the source as well, this one turned out to be the most interesting to me and just left it like that.