# in RISC-V, what is the difference between jump and tail

Tags: riscv

RISC-V assembly features two mnemonics `jump` and `tail`, both of which perform an unconditional jump to another symbol. What is the difference between the two?

Both are pseudo-instructions that get expanded by the assembler but the difference is unclear.

Comment: did you read the [spec](https://riscv.org/technical/specifications/)? There's no `tail` instruction, only pseudoinstruction. And there's `j`, not `jump`. Everything is explained in the spec

Comment: @phuclv, there's no actual `j` either — that's a pseudo instruction for a degenerate `jal` that (doesn't) captures the pc into `x0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write NOT Operation for the Risc-V (Assembly Language)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006052/how-do-i-write-not-operation-for-the-risc-v-assembly-language)

Comment: This is why I said "mnemonic" and not "instruction". Furthermore, the GNU assembler does have a `jump` pseudo instruction

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the GNU assembler understands `tail XXX` as

```
  auipc x6, (something appropriate for XXX)
  jr x6, (something appropriate for XXX)
```

whereas `jump XXX, RR` is understood as

```
  auipc RR, (something appropriate for XXX)
  jr RR, (something appropriate for XXX)
```

In short, `jump` lets you choose the temporary register that gets clobbered by the computation of the destination.

In any case, the GNU linker removes the `auipc` if the target is close enough.

Comment: Can you cite the (presumably GCC/GAS) documentation for these mnemonics?  (Pretty sure linker "relaxation" is responsible for removing the `auipc` when not necessary.)

Comment: If I had documentation about that I would not have to ask on StackOverflow. I saw a compiler emitting `jump`, other emitting `tail`, and both accepted by the assembler. I would specially like to know about possible differences in relocation.

Comment: https://www.sifive.com/blog/all-aboard-part-3-linker-relaxation-in-riscv-toolchain